# Not able to loopover the xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not able to loopover the below xml using for-each loop in xslt.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse>
         <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
            <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
               <sf:type>Type1</sf:type>
               <sf:Id>123</sf:Id>               
            </records>            
            <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
               <sf:type>Type2</sf:type>
               <sf:Id>456</sf:Id>                              
            </records>
           </result>            
      </queryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to loopover the "records" tag by using the xslt for-each as below, but it is returning the empty result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output encoding="iso-8859-1" method="text" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="newline">
         <xsl:text />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:text>Type||Id</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/queryResponse/result/reco‌​rds">
         <xsl:value-of select="//sf:type" />||<xsl:value-of select="//sf:Id" />
         <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output is

```
Type||Id  
Type1||123  
Type2||456
```

Comment: Try `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/queryResponse/result[@xsi:type="QueryResult]/records`

Comment: You need to be aware that `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` is a namespace declaration, not an attribute. -- In addition, you cannot nest double quotes: use single quotes for `QueryResult`, for example.

Comment: Not well formed: Element type "xsl:for-each" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: @YadhuandhanC Post a **complete** stylesheet, so that we can see how (if at all) you have handled the namespaces. Also post the expected result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Yes, I have declared the namespace on top of the xslt xsl:stylesheet. Eventhough if I remove that, the result is same

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I have edited the post with complete xslt and the expected output. It did not allow me to give [@xsi:typ‌​e="QueryResult] in the for-each expression.

Comment: @YadhuandhanC When copy/pasting your code, one finds hidden characters that disable the transformation - e.g. there are ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER characters in `reco••rds` within your `xsl:for-each` instruction.

Comment: Probably not directly related to your problem, but don't put `//` in front of the XPath in your `<xsl:value-of select=".."/>` instructions, that's getting the first such element anywhere in your document, not the child of the one you're trying to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML includes a default namespace declaration `xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"` which you are not handling correctly. You cannot just copy it into your stylesheet as you have done.

Instead, change it to `xpath-default-namespace="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"` (assuming you are indeed using an XSLT 2.0 processor as your stylesheet's version indicates).

Once you do that, your:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/queryResponse/result/reco‌​rds">
     <xsl:value-of select="//sf:type" />||<xsl:value-of select="//sf:Id" />
     <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

will work (sort of, see below).

If you want to restrict the type of result, use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/queryResponse/result[@xsi:type='QueryResult']/records">
```

---

Note that:

```
  <xsl:variable name="newline">
     <xsl:text />
  </xsl:variable>
```

makes no sense. An empty `xsl:text` instruction produces no output.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k,  I changed it to xpath-default-namespace="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" in the xsl:stylesheet element and the error message was **"Not valid.
Error: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: "xpath-default-namespace" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:stylesheet element!"**. 
I removed it and there is no more error, but the output is blank only with 'Type||Id'

Comment: @YadhuandhanC I said this assumes you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor. Are you?

Comment: Thank you so much @micheal.hor257k, The issue was with the xslt processor, fixed by a server restart :-) now the xslt is working as expected by adding the xpath-default-namespace